# acf/validate_value not working on acf 4.4.12

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want my acf field "unique_field" in my custom post type "places" to be unique.

I used acf/validate_value documented here -> https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-validate_value/
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/solved-check-if-value-already-exist-2/

I tried to put this on my `functions.php` but it doesn't work.

```
add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=unique_field', 'validate_unique_field_filter', 10, 4);
function validate_unique_field_filter($valid, $value, $field, $input) {
  if (!$valid || $value == '') {
    return $valid;
  }
  // query posts for the same value
  global $post; 
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'places',
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'unique_field',
        'value' => $value
      )
    )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  if (count($query->posts)) {
    $valid = 'Place already exist';
  }
  return $valid;
}
```

Are there any mistakes? Please Advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. `'meta_key' => 'unique_field'` is missing in the `meta_query` array
2. The filter `acf/validate_value/name=unique_field`
   should be `acf/validate_value/key=field_unique_field`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the correct name of your custom post type is "places", because it is weird to see a post type with a plural name (by default, it is created in singular when you use plugins like ACF or CPT UI). To be sure, replace `'post_type' => 'places'` with `'post_type' => $post->post_type`.